# SHELL: How can I convert a string to timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, math, awk

I'd like to convert string below into timestamp, I already did this into Sheets but I would like to automate this process.

**FROM:**
*38740*

**TO:**
*00:38.74*

In **google sheets**, I insert the formula and works perfectly

```
=TEXT(A2/86400000,"mm:ss.00")
```

In **shell (bash)**:

```
awk "BEGIN {print 38740/86400000}"
```

There's one way to do that using shell or I need to use some programming language more advanced?

Answer (score 2):

Another Bash approach

```
t=$(bc <<< 'scale=2; 38740/1000')
d=$(date -d @"$t" --utc '+%M:%S.%N')
echo "${d:0:9}"
00:38.740
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash, using the builtin arithmetic

```sh
str=38740
(( mins = str / 60000, str %= 60000, secs = str / 1000, msec = str % 1000 ))
printf -v duration "%02d:%02d.%03d" "$mins" "$secs" "$msec"
echo "$duration"
# => 00:38.740
```

Encapsulated into a function:

```sh
milliseconds_to_duration () {
    local mins secs msec
    local tmp=$1
    (( mins = tmp / 60000, tmp %= 60000, secs = tmp / 1000, msec = tmp % 1000 ))
    printf "%02d:%02d.%03d\n" "$mins" "$secs" "$msec"
}
```

then

```sh
$ milliseconds_to_duration 38740
00:38.740
```

Comment: Close? `t=$(bc <<< 'scale=2; 38740/1000'); date -d @"$t" --utc '+%M:%S.%N'  00:38.740000000`